# Affecting only one element with jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have got this code

```
$('.item').click(function () {
    if ($(".secondary", this).is(":hidden")) {
        $(".primary", this).toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500, function () {
            $('.secondary', this).toggle('slide', {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 500);
        });

    }
});
```

Current behavior is that when I click .item, .primary slides to the right, but .secondary doesn't slide in at all.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zm3zp6ax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.item').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($(".secondary", this).is(":hidden")) {
        $(".primary", $this).toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500, function () {
            $('.secondary', $this).toggle('slide', {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 500);
        });

    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zm3zp6ax/1/)

Comment: I can't believe I haven't seen it. Thank you.

Comment: @Seven sometimes we all get confused while coding and sometimes simple things makes problems .. So never mind .. Good Luck :)